# performance tuning : indices of symmetrics in a list

Tags: python, performance

I have a list of list `L` of the following form:

```
   [[[-1, 1], [1, 1]],
   [[0, 0], [1, 1]],
   [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
   [[0, 1], [1, 0]],
   [[1, -1], [1, 1]],
   [[1, 0], [0, 1]],
   [[1, 0], [1, 0]],
   [[1, 1], [-1, 1]],
   [[1, 1], [0, 0]],
   [[1, 1], [1, -1]]]
```

In my current application, if `x=[[a,b],[c,d]]`

is an element of L, then all the other elements found by

-flipping x along its vertical axis : `[[b,a],[d,c]]`
-flipping x along the horizontal axis : `[[c,d],[a,b]]`
-flipping x along the horizontal axis then the vertical axis : `[[d,c],[b,a]]`
-rotating x by 90° : `[[c,a],[d,b]]`
-rotating x by 90° thrice : `[[b,d],[a,c]]`
-transposing x : `[[a,c],[b,d]]`
-transposing x along the antidiagonal : `[[d,b],[c,a]]`

are said to by equivalent to x.

The goal of my application is that given `L` which is **sorted**:
1- I build a series of elements x which I call original states, through which I can rebuild `L` entirely using the symmetry operations above.
2- Return the indices in `L` of all the original states found in step  1.
3- Return for **all states** `y` in `L` the indices of the states found using the symmetries above on `y`, I call the symmetrics of y sym(y).

For example for the L above the program should return:

```
    ([0, 1, 3], #indices of the original states 
    ((4, 7, 9, 4, 7, 0, 9), # indices of the syms(L[0])
    (1, 8, 8, 6, 2, 2, 6), # indices of the syms(L[1])
    (6, 2, 6, 1, 8, 1, 8), # indices of the syms(L[2])
    (5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 3, 3), # indices of the syms(L[3])
    (0, 9, 7, 9, 0, 7, 4), # indices of the syms(L[4])
    (3, 3, 5, 3, 3, 5, 5), # indices of the syms(L[5])
    (2, 6, 2, 8, 1, 8, 1), # indices of the syms(L[6])
    (9, 0, 4, 0, 9, 4, 7), # indices of the syms(L[7])
    (8, 1, 1, 2, 6, 6, 2), # indices of the syms(L[8])
    (7, 4, 0, 7, 4, 9, 0)) # indices of the syms(L[9]))
```

Below I provide a code I have made for doing exactly this.

```
    from more_itertools import distinct_permutations as idp
    import itertools
    import numpy as np
    from bisect import bisect_left
    def FindIndex(a, x):
        'Find leftmost value greater than x'
        i = bisect_left(a, x)
        if i != len(a):
            return i
        raise ValueError
    def flatten(l): # applatit une liste
        return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
    def partition(lst, size): # partitionne une liste
        for i in range(0, len(lst), size):
            yield list(itertools.islice(lst, i, i + size))


    def BuildBasis(m,size,s):
        basis=[x for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(-s,s+1), size**2) if 
    sum(x)==m]
        basis=flatten([list(idp(x)) for x in basis])
        return sorted([list(partition(x,size)) for x in basis])

    def GetUniqueSymmetrics(y):# Return y and all symetrics of y without duplicates
        lr=[list(x) for x in (np.fliplr(y))] #symmetric with respect to the vertical axis
        ud=[list(x) for x in (np.flipud(y))] #symmetric with respect to the horizontal axis
        lrud= [list(x) for x in (np.flipud(lr))] #symmetric with respect to both axes
        r=[list(x) for x in zip(*y[::-1])] # 90° rotation
        rr= [list(x) for x in zip(*r[::-1])] # 180° rotation
        rrr=[list(x) for x in zip(*rr[::-1])] # 270° rotation
        tsp=[list(x) for x in np.transpose(y)] # transposed
        antiTsp=[list(x) for x in ((np.array(y)[::-1,::-1]).T)] # transposed with respect to 
    antidiagonal
        b = list()  # Delete duplicate
        for sublist in [y,lr,ud,lrud,r,rr,rrr,tsp,antiTsp]:
            if sublist not in b:
                b.append(sublist)
        return b # Return y and all symetrics of y without duplicates

    def BuildOriginalStates(m,size,s):# Return original states of  BuildBasis(m,size,s)
        basisStates= BuildBasis(m,size,s)
        originals=[]
        originals+=basisStates[0],
        for x in originals:
            syms=GetUniqueSymmetrics(x)
            for e in syms:
                basisStates.pop(FindIndex(basisStates,e))
            if(len(basisStates)>0):
                originals+=basisStates[0],       
        return originals 

    def Indices(L,originalStates): # Return indices of original states and  the indices of [sym(y) 
    for y in basis]
        lrs=[[list(x) for x in (np.fliplr(e))] for e in L] # generate the symmetrics of all states 
    with respect to vertical axis
        uds=[[list(x) for x in (np.flipud(e))] for e in L] # generate the symmetrics of all states 
    with respect to horizontal axis
        lruds=[[list(x) for x in (np.flipud(e))] for e in lrs] # generate the symmetrics of all 
    states with  respct to ...
        rs=[[list(x) for x in zip(*e[::-1])] for e in L]
        rrs=[[list(x) for x in zip(*e[::-1])] for e in rs]
        rrrs=[[list(x) for x in zip(*e[::-1])] for e in rrs]
        tsps=[[list(x) for x in np.transpose(e)] for e in L]
        antiTsps=[[list(x) for x in ((np.array(e)[::-1,::-1]).T)] for e in L]

        originalIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in originalStates] # find the indices of the orginal 
    states
        lrIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in lrs] # find the indices of the symmetrics with respect
    to vertical axis 
        udIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in uds]# find the indices of the symmetrics with respect 
    to horizontal axis 
        lrudIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in lruds] #....
        rIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in rs]
        rrrIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in rrrs]
        tspIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in tsps]
        antiTspIndices=[FindIndex(L,e) for e in antiTsps]

        return originalIndices,tuple([tuple(x) for x in
        np.transpose([lrIndices,udIndices,lrudIndices,rIndices,rrrIndices,tspIndices,
        antiTspIndices])])
```

you should find the example of the question with m=2,size=2,s=1

```
m,size,s =2,2,1
base=BuildBasis(m,size,s)
Indices(base,BuildOriginalStates(m,size,s))
```

Q: I am new to python and this is pretty slow ! How can I improve on the speed of these operations, in particular the first and third step?

Comment: you forgot to provide the function `idp`

Comment: I have edited my question @GáborFekete see the imports